# .click() issue on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got an issue with the jquery .click() method.
The problem is if I open the website on mobile I have to click two times on the element to get it work. If I already have clicked two times on it and I want to click on the same element again then one click is enough.
And I have the exactly same issue with all each element.

But this issue only on mobile browsers(Chrome, firefox). No issue at all on desktop PC. Here is my script:

```
$(function() {    
    $('#images img').on('click', function() {
        var attr = $(this).attr('data-number');
        if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
            var number = $(this).data('number');
            console.log(number);
            $.ajax("text.json", {
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {    
                    $(".images_ajax").css('display', 'block');
                    $(".images_ajax_sub").append(response[number]);
                }
            }),
            $(function() {
                $('.close_ajax').click(function() {
                    $(".images_ajax_sub h1, .images_ajax_sub p").remove();
                    $(".images_ajax").css('display', 'none');
                })
            })
        }
    })
});
```

I have added the `.on()` method because I read on this site may it can be an issue using only the `.click()` method. But it does not work either.

Thank you for your helps

Comment: Do the elements in question have a `:hover` style set? Some mobile devices/browsers try to make hover work by making the first tap on an element set it into the hover state, and let only the second tap activate standard “click” behavior.

Comment: in what phone are you testing? is mobile browser or is webkit? are you aware of the 300ms delay on iphone/android?

Comment: No there is not any :hover style set at all. I am using Android device to test the website

Comment: It must be a device issue. I have got a Moto G and test always on this phone. Never got this kind of problem before. On my wife's LG phone and the Samsung Tab works fine. Thank you for the helps